# How to add space between posts when using Wordpress with Toolbox theme

Tags: css, wordpress, toolbox

I am looking for a way to add space between Wordpress posts when using the
popular Toolbox theme.

If anybody could tell me where too put that "margin-bottom" tag I would be very glad!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.post` is the `class` applied to the entire post and it's not included in the default stylesheet for your theme so you'll have to add it.

In this file:

```
/wp-content/themes/toolbox/style.css
```

Under the "Content" section, add this class & style:

```
.post {
    margin-bottom: 80px;  /* <--- whatever you need */
}
```

`80px` is arbitrary... use whatever size/units you'd like.